# CSS Drop down menu won't display when mouse hover beyond wrapping div

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am working on a simple css drop down menu, when I hover the list, the drop down displays, but when my mouse move beyond the "#head" wrapper div the list closes.

the head div is wraps the menu and my logo and a search bar.
The content div wraps all my contents.

When there is content below the "head" div, say another "content" div, then the drop down list displays until i move the cursor beyond the "head" div

```
div#content{
    display:block;
    width:972;
    float:none;
    position:relative;
}
#top_menu{
    float:right;
    text-align: left;
    width: 505px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

#top_menu ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    float:right;
}
#top_menu ul li ul{
    display:none;
}
#top_menu ul li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 14px;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
}
#top_menu ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
#top_menu ul li:hover ul li{
    clear: left; 
}
#top_menu a{
    display:block;
}



    <div id="head">
        <div id = "top_menu">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="1.php">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="2.php">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="3.php">3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="4.php">4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="5.php">5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="6.php">6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="search">
            <form action="search.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" maxlength="30" width="40" />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, what's the CSS for the #head elements and can you get a copy up onto jsFiddle to look at?

Comment: Actually your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2tRUt/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... i fixed it by adding a z-index, turns out the content div, which is attached below the head div, is covering up the drop down box. so in the css, i just added: z-index:1000, then it worked. thanks all.